# Showing different js file for different theme in wordpress customizer api

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I have two themes. All files are same on those two themes but few js files are different. Suppose, When i will select `Theme One`, I want to to load the whole themplate files and `theme-one.js` file, in this time,`theme-two.js` will not be loaded . Again , when I will select `Theme Two`, i want to load the whole template and `theme-two.js` file. In this time, `theme-one.js` will not be loaded.

I want to select themes in customize api and want to see the changed theme on the live preview. 
what can i do?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried before asking for a complete code?

Comment: @MaxYudin i never asked for a complete code to anyone, i am not that weird. I want the concept or any idea. thanks for your concern.